# compressing multiple folders in one CompressedFolders.rar file in Java

Tags: java, compression

good day!

Let's say that I have a folder named **"Data"** which contains multiple folders:

- Data1_Folder.
- Data2_Folder.
- Data3_Folder.
- Data4_Folder.

and I need to compress only Data2_Folder and Data3_Folder, In another words, the user will decide which folders he wants to compress.

I'm using a **for loop** to read data from DB for chosen IDs and write these data in separate **excel** sheets. all of the files will be stored under their **ID name folder** (**Data#_Folder**) under the main **Data** folder.

at the end of the loop these are the statements to create the file and compress them.

```
Excel.writeFile((String)DataID.get(i),TempArray);
Folder2Compress = new String[]{CompressingFolders.CompressFiles("D:\\Data/"+DataID.get(i).toString())};
```

unfortunately, only the last created folder will be compressed. How can I make it to compress all chosen folders?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add only a single folder to the array `Folder2Compress`. Use a `List<String>` instead and add all folders to the list:

```
List<String> folders = new ArrayList<String>();
for( .... ) {
    ...
    folders.add("D:\\Data/"+DataID.get(i));
}
```

Now you can change `CompressingFolders.CompressFiles()` to take this list as input and add all folders to the result.

Note: You may want to look at the [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).